# How to show No data found in angular list without datasource using observable

Tags: angular

```
 <tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let markup of markups$ | async; let i=index">
    <td class="mat-cell">{{markup.category}}</td>
    <td class="mat-cell">{{markup.markup_percent}}</td>
    <td class="mat-cell">{{markup.markup_flatrate}}</td>
     <td class="mat-cell"><span *ngIf="markup.baseline"> Default Markup </span></td>
     <td class="mat-cell"><button  mat-icon-button matSuffix>
   <mat-icon [routerLink]="[markup.id]">edit</mat-icon>
  </button> <button (click)="deleteMarkup(markup.client_name,markup.id)"  mat-icon-button matSuffix>
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
  </button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngIf="! markups$"> <td colspan="3">No data Found</td> <td> + Add Default Markup <mat-icon [routerLink]="add-default-markup">Add</mat-icon> </td></tr>
```

I want to show the No data found row in case markups$ doesnt have data. How to do that?
*ngIf="! markups$" doesn't work

Comment: You can use `*ngIf="!(markups$ | async).length`

Comment: A little add-on to @MichalTkacyzk answer. You can also have an `else` as such: `*ngIf="!(markups$ | async).length; else noMarkups"` and `<ng-template #noMarkups>...</ng-template>`. `*ngIf` can be bound to every element, but the else case only to `ng-template`

Answer (score 1):

I would surround your elements bei 2 `ng-container`, which provides you control over the marksups value. The empty data is provided by a `ng-template`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="markups$ | async as markups">
  <ng-container *ngIf="markups.length > 0; else noContent">
    <tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let markup of markups; let i=index">
      <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
  
  <ng-template #noContent>
    <td colspan="3">No data Found</td> <td> + Add Default Markup <mat-icon [routerLink]="add-default-markup">Add</mat-icon> </td></tr>
  <ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @MoxxiManagarm! that works! Just one edit required...the closing tag for ng-template.